# How can one route a search URL which has a query string embedded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am working on an express application and I have two GET URLs. One fetches all resources in the database but is right-protected(needs authentication and admin access) while the other fetches resources based on a search parameter(query string).

The route that requires authentication looks like so:

`carRouter.get('/car', verifyToken, isAdmin, fetchAllCarAds);`

This means that the admin has to be logged in first and then a check is carried out to ascertain whether he is truly an admin before he is given access. Now I have another GET route that doesn't require authentication like so
:

`carRouter.get('/car?status=unsold', filterUnsoldCars);`.

I understand that express does not allow routing based on query strings so how do I ensure that the request that does not require authentication(query string) is accessible in the one without query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following things to make it work.

- Check either query string exist or not inside `isAdmin` middleware
- If query string exists, Skip validation that has been implemented inside middleware.
- If query string doesn't exist, then check either user is an admin or not.

Comment: Please upvote and mark as correct answer if this solves your problem. So that others can take advantage of this.

Comment: @camelCase Please check Is this helpful now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by placing it before the verifyToken function and it worked. I would like to learn of other ways of doing it if there are. Thanks

`carRouter.get('/car', filterUnsoldCars, verifyToken, isAdminDummy, fetchAllCarAds);`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are building a proper routing but, you can use a middleware to check query params and bypasses to the next route assigned. check below routing explanation for **next('route')**

[Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

```
carRouter.get('/car', hasParams, verifyToken, isAdminDummy, fetchAllCarAds);
carRouter.get('/car?status=unsold', filterUnsoldCars);
```

if hasParams true, next('route')

if hasParams false, next()